# plural of "terminal accounts"

Tags: plural-forms

As far as I know, a set of numbers about a company like net sales, net income and so on that is published at the end of year is called "terminal accounts".

If information about a year are referred to as a plural noun, what do I call a set of terminal accounts?

I mean, when I refer to several years of company terminal accounts what should I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s still “terminal accounts”. As far as pluralization is concerned, there’s either one of something or more than one. In this case, each year ends with terminal accounts, and several years yield several more terminal accounts.

What you can do is say things like what you’ve written in your question here. Make the distinction between one year’s terminal accounts and several sets of terminal accounts. “Set” is a great word here, because it groups the already-plural accounts into one set (one year’s worth) and/or multiple sets.